# Difference betweeen SPSite.Features.Add(...) and SPWeb.Features.Add(...)

Tags: feature-activation

I have created a Feature named Feature1. Feature1 is activated in a SharePoint site. I create a Web Part that contains the following code.

```
SPSite site = new SPSite("http://intranet/site1");

SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb();

SPFeatureDefinition feature = SPFarm.Local.FeatureDefinitions("Feature1");
```

I need to modify the Web Part to activate Feature1 in Site1 only.

Should I use?
site.Features.Add(feature.Id) 
or
web.Features.Add(feature.Id)

Whats the difference between the two instructions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the object model, an SPSite is a Site Collection, whereas an SPWeb is a site.  Yes, it is a little confusing.

So if you have a feature that needs to be activated at the Site level (not Site Collection level), then you want to use the SPWeb, which your code calls web.

Answer (score 2):

The difference is the scope of the Feature, which depends on the content of the feature. Here's a starter for reading material about this:

http://weblogs.asp.net/soever/archive/2007/05/03/sharepoint-features-elements-scope-and-other-info.aspx

Answer (score 2):

```
if (feature.Scope == SPFeatureScope.Web)
 web.Features.Add(feature.Id)
else if (feature.Scope == SPFeatureScope.Site)
 site.Features.Add(feature.Id)
```

Answer (score 1):

Luis based on your question

> I need to modify the Web Part to activate Feature1 in Site1 only

You should use
    `web.Features.Add(feature.Id);`